# Getting Integer division and modulo by zero error

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, longest-substring

I'm getting **Integer Division or Modulo by zero** error.

```
def getProduct(n): 
    product = 1
    while (n != 0): 
        product = product * (n % 10) 
        n = n // 10
    return product 

def printSubstrings(n):
    s=int(math.log10(n))
    d=(math.pow(10,s))
    k=d
    count = 0
    while n>0:
        while d>0:
            ans=0
            ans = getProduct(n//d)
            if ans%4==0 or ans%2!=0:
                count+=1
            d=int(d/10)
        n = int(n%k)
        k = int(k//10)
        d = k
    print(count)
```

Simple Inputs are running well but On entering Large input data it gives **ZERODIVISIONERROR**
on large input

> 10
>   11903030 2093524 04935049 09024 12242910 109310 1000901 103412 102901 10290191

Error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/CodeWork/Code Challenge/rough.py", line 271, in <module>
    printSubstrings(num)
  File "e:/CodeWork/Code Challenge/rough.py", line 261, in printSubstrings
    n = int(n%k)
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure `k != 0` holds before you compute `n % k`.

Since the modulus operator `%` is implemented by finding the remainder upon division, you will get a division by zero error if you try to evaluate `n % 0` for any integer `n`.